# Taking a timed input in java while simultaneously displaying the countdown timer

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I am trying to build a simple game in Java in which the user is prompted to enter a number in 10 seconds. Meanwhile a countdown timer should also be displayed for showing the amount of seconds left and the countdown timer should stop and reset to 10 as soon the user enters some input.
I was able to find questions on taking timed input in java and also questions on showing a countdown timer but I wasn't able to combine both of these to get a effective solution. If a similar question has been answered please paste a link to it for my reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Example: If you have a Socket connection, you can wait on the InputStream using a read() call, and in another thread you can set a timer which closes the InputStream on time out. If data is available before the timer completes, you reset the timer

Comment: you could look into Timeline() and KeyFrame() for the countdown timer. edit: this depends on what you use to build a UI for your game. JavaFX?

Comment: it sounds like while you have one thread to do the countdown, you have another thread to receive input. On input received, if the countdown is not over, send a message to the other thread to instruct the timer to stop, and reset it.

Comment: *I was able to find questions on taking timed input in java and also questions on showing a countdown timer but none which asked for a combination of both.* - and what is to prevent you from taking both solutions and combining them into a specific solution for your requirement? This is how programming works. Rarely will you find code that does exactly what you want. So learn the concept of both solutions and make changes as required. If you have a problem, then post your [mre] demonstrating what you tried. We don't even know what toolkit you are using.